# Unexpected Behavior in PyTorch LSTM for Complex Time Series Forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on a project for time series forecasting/prediction using LSTMs implemented in PyTorch Lightning. My data consists of samples from a complex signal (a + ib), where each sample is a complex number. The signal contains several thousand elements, and I break it down into contiguous windows of size W (typically 32). This leads to a torch.complex64 tensor of shape [W]. I then use torch.view_as_real to get a torch.float32 tensor of shape [W, 2], which is what the **getitem** function returns from my dataset `base_dataset`.

Here's how I divide my dataset into training and validation sets and prepare my dataloaders:

```py
# Divide dataset into training and validation sets
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(base_dataset, [0.75, 0.25])

logger.info(f'Training & validation dataset size: {len(train_dataset)} / {len(val_dataset)}')
logger.info(f'Preparing dataloaders')
dataloaders = {
    'train': DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=B, shuffle=True, num_workers=0, pin_memory=True),
    'val': DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=B, shuffle=False, num_workers=0, pin_memory=True) 
}

logger.info(f'Start training')
trainer.fit(network, dataloaders['train'], dataloaders['val'])
```

When feeding data into my LSTM, I have a tensor shape of [B, W, 2]. Based on the usual LSTM input understanding, my "sequence_length" should be W, and the number of features should be 2. Therefore, my LSTM would be initialized like this:

```py
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(2, 64, 4, batch_first=True, dropout=0.02)
# ... Linear layers to obtain a [B, 1, 2] output
```

And I should pass my batch directly through the LSTM without any change.

However, using this setup, my network does not converge. Oddly enough, when I swap dimensions 1 and 2 (resulting in an input shape of [B, 2, W]) and modify my LSTM as follows:

```py
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(W, 64, 4, batch_first=True, dropout=0.02)
# ... Linear layers to obtain a [B, 1, 2] output
```

The network converges and yields good results.

This observation contradicts my understanding of what a "feature" and what a "sequence_length" should be. I'm puzzled as to why the latter case works but not the former. Any insights or recommendations would be highly appreciated :).

Thank you!